# Array Index out of bounds! Java Counting runs

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error of

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20

I am not sure if I am suppose to have a while loop or break it so it doesn't go over the array length. I see other posts telling why its happening but I don't see any showing how to fix it. Please help!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package secondarray;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author iii
 */
public class SecondArray {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random generator = new Random();
        int[]run= new int[20];
          for (int i= 0;i<run.length;i++)
       {
           run[i]=generator.nextInt(6)+1;

       }
          marking(run);
    }
    public static void marking(int[] run){

       for (int i =0;i<run.length;i++){
           while(run[i]<= run[20]){

           if(run[i]==run[i-1]&&run[i]==run[i+1] ){
               System.out.print(run[i]);
           }
           if(run[i]!=run[i-1]&&run[i]==run[i+1]){
              System.out.print("("+run[i]);
           }
           if(run[i]==run[i-1]&& run[i]!=run[i+1]){
               System.out.print(run[i]+")");
                }
           if(run[i]!=run[i-1]&& run[i] == run[i+1]){
               System.out.print(run[i]);
                }

           }
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: `for (int i =0;i<=run.length;i++){` should be `for (int i =0;i<run.length - 1;i++){` since you access `i + 1`. You should probably start with `i = 1` too, since you access `i - 1` as well.

Comment: The `<=` in your `for (int i =0;i<=run.length;i++){` should be `<` just like it is in your `for (int i= 0;i<run.length;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= run.length; i++){
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < run.length; i++){
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= run.length-1; i++){
```

You start to loop throw your array from 0 so you should to stop in `length-1` and not in `length` your array and indexes should look like this :

```
Values    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Indexes   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**EDIT**

You try to compare the follow and the previous value, so i think you need to make something like this (no need for the `while()` loop and make sure to start your loop from `1` and stop in `lenght -2` ) like this `(int i = 1; i < run.length - 1; i++)`, so your program should look like this :

```
for (int i = 1; i < run.length - 1; i++) {

    if (run[i] == run[i - 1] && run[i] == run[i + 1]) {
        System.out.print(run[i]);
    }
    if (run[i] != run[i - 1] && run[i] == run[i + 1]) {
        System.out.print("(" + run[i]);
    }
    if (run[i] == run[i - 1] && run[i] != run[i + 1]) {
        System.out.print(run[i] + ")");
    }
    if (run[i] != run[i - 1] && run[i] == run[i + 1]) {
        System.out.print(run[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this and now it will just say run and not output anything or stop            `for (int i =0;i<=run.length-1;i++){
           while(run[i]<= run[run.length -1]){`

Answer (score 0):

The `<=` in your `for (int i =0;i<=run.length;i++){` should be `<` just like it is in your `for (int i= 0;i<run.length;i++)`.

Additionally, in an `int[20]`, the indexes are `0` through `19` (inclusive), so you can't use `run[20]` here:

```
while(run[i]<= run[20]){
// Error ---------^^^^
```

The last entry in `run` is `run[19]`.

Taking it further: `marking` shouldn't assume it knows how many entries there are in `run`, so it really should be:

```
while(run[i]<= run[run.length - 1]){
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for (int i =0;i<=run.length;i++)`
with
 `for (int i =0;i<run.length;i++)`   in  marking method.

Because the last index of any array is length - 1.